# Clarion based application in WinServer 2016, frozen. Suggestions needed on tools we could use to gather more information

Tags: windows, sybase, clarion

I have a clarion application running in Win Server 2016 talking to a sybase DB, over the past few weeks we find the application gets frozen for different users at a given time. However the user can leave the session as such and start a new one and that works good. The users are known to use multiple instances of the same application in one remote server or on multiple servers. Having said that, I wanted to get more information on the freezeup and looked through the application event logs in the system where I see explorer.exe crashes but these correlate to the time of occurrence of the issue at certain times but not always, checked the DB transaction logs from Sybase and I do not find any crashes, errors or stuck connections. Having said that, since I have exhausted all possible options I am reaching out to you guys to know if there are any other places that i can look for to gather more information.

I would love to know of any application / tools that we could use to gather logs of a frozen clarion application on windows. Also good to know if anyone has faced such a situation and where and how have you guys looked into the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarion's runtime library and database drivers expect a persistent connection. Disconnects that are normal with remote ODBC can cause a problem (including app hangs) unless you test for them at the ABC file mgr level and reconnect, or use similar steps to test and recover.

If you're looking for specifics about what's going on between the driver and the SQL backend, I suggest using Clarion's database driver trace facilities. From the help topic: "*Logging Driver I/O for debugging*":

To view the trace details in debugview, name the target trace file "DEBUG:"

Logging opens the named logfile for exclusive access. If the file exists, the new log data is appended to the file.

**On Demand Logging**

For on-demand logging you can use property syntax within your program to conditionally turn various levels of logging on and off. The logging is effective for the target table and any view for which the target table is the primary table.

```
file{PROP:Profile}=Pathname   !Turns Clarion I/O logging on
file{PROP:Profile}="DEBUG:"   !Turns Clarion I/O logging on and 
                              !sends output via OutputDebugString()
                              !(viewable via debugview, etc)

file{PROP:Profile}=''         !Turns Clarion I/O logging off

PathName = file{PROP:Profile} !Queries the name of the log file

file{PROP:Log}=string         !Writes the string to the log file
file{PROP:Log}="DEBUG:"       !Writes the string to the log file

file{PROP:Details}=1          !Turns Record Buffer logging on

fFile{PROP:Details}=0         !Turns Record Buffer logging off
```

where Pathname is the full pathname or the filename of the log file to create. If you do not specify a path, the driver writes the log file to the current directory.

You can also accomplish on demand logging with a SEND() command and the LOGFILE driver string. See LOGFILE for more information.

Example I use frequently, which was based on the help above:

```
SYSTEM{PROP:DriverTracing} = '1'
 CRMNotes{PROP:TraceFile} = 'DEBUG:'
 CRMNotes{PROP:Details}=1 
 CRMNotes{PROP:Profile}= 'DEBUG:' 
 CRMNotes{PROP:LogSQL} = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Mark... This helped..!

Comment: Cool. BTW, there are a couple of pretty active Clarion Skype groups. Look for cw-talk and Clarion Live.

Comment: That would be amazing..! Will be sure to join.. Thanks again Mark